# Identity involving the Catalan numbers and binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

Let $C_k := \frac{1}{k + 1} \binom{2k}{k}$ be the $k$-th Catalan number and let $K$ be a positive integer.

I am looking for an identity or simplification of

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k = 0}^K C_k \binom{K + k}{K - k} z^k
\end{equation}

that does not involve a summation. Mathematica returns the ordinary hypergeometric function $_2F_1(-K,K + 1,2,-z)$, but that still involves a summation. Can anyone point me to a reference that could show me the right direction?

Comment: References and a generating function $$\frac 12 \left(1 - x\,z - \sqrt{(1-x\,z)^2 - 4\,x}\right)=x+(1+z)x^2+(2+3z+z^2)x^3+\cdots$$ are available at [OEIS entry A060693](https://oeis.org/A060693) but your starting point contains already the coefficients in closed form...

Comment: To get the correct progression of the powers of $z$ use rather following G.F.  from [A088617](https://oeis.org/A088617) :
$$\frac {1 - x - \sqrt{(1-x)^2 - 4\,x\,z}}{2\,x\,z}=1+(1+z)x+(1+3z+2z^2)x^2+(1+6z+10z^2+5z^3)x^3\cdots$$